# NEO4J Cypher query slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have tried hard to optimize the following query but can't get it down to under two minutes - is this expected? Is there any way I can speed things up. I have added indexes and used `WITH` wherever possible.

```
match (md:MarketingDetail {Status: 'Live'})
with md limit 10
match (md) -[:Has_Area]-> (a:Area)
with md, a
match (ss:SavedSearch) -[:Has_Area]->(a)
with md, ss match
(md) -[:Has_Trade] -> (st:SectorTrade) <-[:Has_Trade]- (ss)
where ((md.FreeholdTenure ='Freehold'
and ss.FreeholdTenure = 'true'
and (md.FreeholdSearchPrice >= ss.PriceFrom
or md.FreeholdSearchPrice is null)
and (md.FreeholdSearchPrice <= ss.PriceTo
or md.FreeholdSearchPrice is null))
or (md.LeaseholdTenure is not null
and ss.LeaseholdTenure = 'true'
and (md.LeaseholdSearchPrice >= ss.PriceFrom
or md.LeaseholdSearchPrice is null)
and (md.LeaseholdSearchPrice <= ss.PriceTo
or md.LeaseholdSearchPrice is null)))
return count(ss)
```

Here is the profile of the above query -

[image: Query Profile]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your PROFILE output (expand all boxes and share the screenshot)? You don't need the WITH statements after the first.

Comment: I have added the results of the PROFILE to the question above - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your graph and its structure/size, it's hard to know exactly how to query it efficiently. At the moment your query seems to match every `md` and `ss` combination before querying for the desired pattern, this may or may not be the best approach depending on the graph, but I've tried an alternative below.

You can put `PROFILE` before a query to see how it executed and look for bottlenecks. Could you post the results of this, as well as your indexes by running `:schema`??

```
MATCH (md:MarketingDetail {Status: 'Live'})
WHERE 
  (
    md.FreeholdTenure ='Freehold'
    OR md.LeaseholdTenure is not null
    OR md.LeaseholdSearchPrice is null
    OR md.LeaseholdSearchPrice is null
  )
WITH md LIMIT 10
match (md) -[:Has_Area]-> (a:Area)<-[:Has_Area]-(ss:SavedSearch)-[:Has_Trade]->(st:SectorTrade)-[:Has_Trade]->(md)
where
  AND
  (
    md.FreeholdTenure ='Freehold'
    and ss.FreeholdTenure = 'true'
    and (md.FreeholdSearchPrice >= ss.PriceFrom or md.FreeholdSearchPrice is null)
    and (md.FreeholdSearchPrice <= ss.PriceTo or md.FreeholdSearchPrice is null)
  )
  or (
    md.LeaseholdTenure is not null
    and ss.LeaseholdTenure = 'true'
    and (
      md.LeaseholdSearchPrice >= ss.PriceFrom
      or md.LeaseholdSearchPrice is null
    )
    and (
      md.LeaseholdSearchPrice <= ss.PriceTo
      or md.LeaseholdSearchPrice is null
    )
  )  
return count(ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `PROFILE`, you do not have an index for `:MarketingDetail(Status)`, which is very important to have for your query, since that is needed by the first `MATCH`.

In addition, restructuring your query (possibly in the way @DonWeldon suggests) should be helpful.